# wp localizing script not works

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Here i followed the solution here to localize script : [Problem in wp_localize_script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206836/problem-in-wp-localize-script)

But its not working.

Below is my codes:

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( array("jquery") );

    wp_enqueue_script('thebootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',         

    wp_localize_script('reservation-scripts', 'admin_ajax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => esc_url(admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
    ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'reservation-scripts' );
    /*
    * Scripts for IE9
    */
    wp_enqueue_script('thehtml5shiv', '//oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js');
    wp_script_add_data('thehtml5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');
    wp_enqueue_script('therespond', '//oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js');
    wp_script_add_data('therespond', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong...the most pertinent of which is that the script that you're going to localize with [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) must be registered **before** you call `wp_localize_script()`.

Secondly, your call to `wp_enqueue_script( 'reservation-scripts' )` doesn't provide the source (i.e., URL) for the script.

Lastly, they way you are enqueueing jQuery is incorrect.

So, if you change your code to the following you'll be fine:

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('thebootstrap',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery') ) ;

    // be sure to substitute the actual URL for
    // your script in URL_FOR_YOUR_SCRIPT
    wp_register_script( 'reservation-scripts', URL_FOR_YOUR_SCRIPT );
    wp_localize_script('reservation-scripts', 'admin_ajax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => esc_url(admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
    ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'reservation-scripts' );
    /*
     * Scripts for IE9
     */
    wp_enqueue_script('thehtml5shiv', '//oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js');
    wp_script_add_data('thehtml5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');
    wp_enqueue_script('therespond', '//oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js');
    wp_script_add_data('therespond', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts');
```

Comment: thanks a lot.Btw i don't understand `URL_FOR_YOUR_SCRIPT` .which url?

Comment: it would be something like `get_template_directory_uri()  . 'js/your_script.js'`

Comment: okay but is it necessary to localize admin-ajax?